# Show Snackbar above all widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to use `Snackbar` with root `Scaffold` widget to show many messages from different places like this:

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
  content: Text('$message'),
  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
));
```

But when I have some widget(e.g. another `Scaffold` which I can't use) which fully above my root widget, I don't see the `Snackbar`.

So, how can I show the `Snackbar` above all widgets?

Comment: You can use the Scaffold.of(context) to find out the nearest Scaffold. Is that enough?

Comment: @Darish nope, unfortunately. I have `BlocListener` in the my root widget, necessary messages come there

Comment: So you trigger some asynchronous action on Route A, navigate to Route B, the async action completes and you want to display a Snackbar on top of Route B? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122105/flutter-modifying-scaffold-to-track-currently-displayed-scaffolds-buildcontext and modify it to use your Bloc instead of Provider

Comment: @Ovidiu sorry for the long delay, I had other tasks. Thanks, but as I understand, if I show Snackbar on the route A, this solution will close the Snackbar when I go to the route B, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, but that's how Snackbars work.. Have a look for 3rd party packages or an Overlay-based solution if the default behavior is not satisfactory.